# Как создать папку а в этой папке создать текстовый файл и записать туда текст? Python

Tags: python

у меня есть переменная с путём
`filename = f'src/download/video_{random.randint(1, 99999)}'`, папки `scr/download` есть, мне нужно создать папку `video_{random.randint(1, 99999)}`, где `random.randint(1, 99999)` это рандомные цифры что-бы папки не повторялись, и в этой папке(`video_{random.randint(1, 99999)}`) нужно создать к примеру файл `name.txt` и записать туда свой текст, я не знаю как мне это сделать. Помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это сделать можно вот так:

```
import os
import datetime


my_text = 'Hello world!!!'

# Рандомные цифры в названии не подойдут.
# Потому что они повторяются
path = f'src/download/video_{datetime.datetime.now().time()}'

# Создаем директорию
try:
    os.makedirs(path)
except FileExistsError:
    print('Директория уже существует')

# Создаем файл и записываем в него текст
with open(os.path.join(path,'name.txt'), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(my_text)
```